# List of API scopes for Google Apps domain-wide delegation

Tags: google-api, google-apps

Is there a full list of the API scopes available for domain-wide delegation, as per the instructions here?: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scopes that you need depend on the API that you are calling. See [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) for a complete list.

Comment: Thanks- for Goole Apps admin apis, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35242008/165673)

Answer (score 1):

You can find from [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) from mentioned scopes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: While [@Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35228781/165673) covers the standard Google services, they don't include scopes for the Google Apps [admin apis](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/).

To get scopes for the admin apis, choose the service you want from [this page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/), and click "Authorize Requests" in the left menu.

Example: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing